# Dynamic loading in Golang?

Tags: java, go

I've got a common project and small projects which act such as connectors in the common project.

I want to create a common project such that when a new connector is  developed I don’t have to modify code in the common project. Is it possible to dynamically load the structures in Go, only knowing the path (by putting this path in a file in common project and at runtime load that struct) of the struct and its folders?

```
connector1
  connector1.go
  /util
  /domain

connectorN
  connectorN.go 
  /domain

commonProject
   main.go
   config.ini
```

Structure config.ini

```
Conector
name = connector1
path = ..../connector1/connector1.go

Conector
name = connectorN
path = ..../connectorN/connectorN.go
```

I know that this is possible to do this in Java with code like this, but I am trying to do this in Go. Any ideas?

```
Class.forName(String)
```

or

```
ClassLoader.loadClass(String):
```

Comment: This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it might get you closer: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/dependency-injection-with-go/

Answer (score 1):

In Java classes are loaded dynamically, on demand, when they are used/referred to.

Go produces statically linked native binaries without external dependencies, so you can't load new "types" or "functions" in a way you can do in Java with the `Class.forName()` (at least not code written in Go).

Answer (score 1):

I can see two ways to achieve what you describe, but keep in mind, as @icza pointed out, that go produces static binaries, so you can't load external libraries dynamically.

You can, however:

- use `cgo` to interface with C code, and load external libraries that
  way.
- use the `net/rpc` package to have several binaries communicate
  with each other, and load those on demand.