# How to dynamically add imports

Tags: go

I want to dynamically create an HTTP router using custom [plugins/middleware](https://violetear.org/post/middleware/), currently, I am using a `config.yml` for example:

```
plugins:
  - waf
  - jwt 
  - cors
```

After parsing the `yml` file  I create the routes like this:

```
route := violetear.New()
chain := middleware.New() 
for _, plugin := range Plugins {
    chain := chain.Append(plugin)       
}
router.Handle("/test", chain.Then(myHandler))
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
```

For this to work, I would have to include all the plugins in the import section, something like:

```
import (
   "net/http"

   "github.com/nbari/violetear"
   "github.com/nbari/violetear/midleware"

   // How to deal with this
   "github.com/example/waf"
   "github.com/example/jwt"
   "github.com/example/cors"
)
```

I would need to change the current config format to be something more useful/generic probably something like:

```
plugins:
  - [github.com/foo, foo]
  - [github.com/bar, bar]
```

But besides that what could be the best approach to "dynamically" create the imports or to generate the code the one later could be compiled?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go is a statically linked language. This means if a package is not referenced at compile time (from your `.go` source files), that package will not be linked / compiled into the executable binary, which implies it will not be availabe at runtime.

So the easiest is to just use imports.

If you want truly dynamic configuration, [plugins](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/) introduced in Go 1.8 may be an option for you, but using plugins complicates things and I would only use that as a last resort. Also note that plugins currently only work on linux.

Related questions:

[Dynamic loading in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097451/dynamic-loading-in-golang/30102141#30102141)

[Go Plugin variable initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181410/go-plugin-variable-initialization/43181795#43181795)

[go 1.8 plugin use custom interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388090/go-1-8-plugin-use-custom-interface/42389345#42389345)

Comment: hi, I have been thinking about using `go generate`  and use a `Makefile` to generate and later build maybe could work any thoughts?

Comment: @nbari Yeah, if you're fine with pre-processing, go generate can be useful, but it won't be dynamic as you requested in the first sentence of your question.